# How does one use the Latin word “cum” in a sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is this usage correct:

The Tim Smith show takes listeners through Tim's day to day life as a broadcasting legend cum podcaster.

Are the dashes "-" necessary?

and is the broadcasting legend too much?  Should it only be Noun-cum-noun?

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, The only use I have for that word is in conjunction with *magna/summa cum laude*.  Why would you want to use it and not *turned* in that sentence?

Comment: Using *cum* in that way is vaguely pretentious. I recommend it only if you've fallen out of love with the English language.